# Discord.js Filter Discord Events From Only 1 Server

Tags: discord.js

I am working on trying to filter events for only 1 server rather than all servers the bot is in, but I'm trying to figure out how to exactly save each guild the bot is in as an collection so I can just filter events based on a guild ID I desire. Is this even possible? This is a snippet of the code I have to date, it's able to display the server names and ID's the bot is currently in, the events are working properly but triggering for all servers rather than the one I desire, how would I go about filtering for one guild collection?

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const config = require('./config.json')

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
    //Sets Activity
    //client.user.setStatus('invisible')
    bot.user.setActivity("Discord Cooks", { type: "WATCHING"})
    console.log("Set User Activity!");
    //Online Webhook
    const webhookClient = new Discord.WebhookClient('','');
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()    
        .setTitle(`${bot.user.tag} is online`)
        .setColor('#FFFF00')
        .setTimestamp()
    webhookClient.send(embed);
    
    bot.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
        console.log(guild.name, guild.id);
    });
});

bot.on("channelCreate", (channel) => {
    console.log(`channelCreate: ID: ${channel.id} Name: ${channel.name}`);
});

bot.on("channelUpdate", (oldChannel, newChannel) => {
    console.log(`channelUpdate -> ${oldChannel.name} to ${newChannel.name}`);
});

bot.on("channelDelete", (channel) => {
    console.log(`channelDelete: ID: ${channel.id} Name: ${channel.name}`);
});

bot.login(config.bottoken)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only execute code if event happened on exact server in much easier way:

```js
if(guild.id == "GUILD_ID") {
// code
}
```

Also as @MrMythical said, you can just use `if (message.guild.id !== "GUILD_ID") return;` if you only need to run your code for 1 guild!

Comment: Even better, just put `if (message.guild.id !== "GUILD_ID") return;`

Comment: @MrMythical this is only a solution if they want to execute code for one guild, but what if they want to execute different code for different guilds

Comment: *"I am working on trying to filter events for only 1 server rather than all servers the bot is in"* - @MegaMix_Craft this is from the question, and specifies that they want only 1 server

Comment: @MrMythical but my answer is more universal because other people may face similar problem, but they will need more than 1 server

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft How exactly would you structure this with the current code, because the only way that would make sense to me would be inside a `bot.on('message', msg => {}` function as it would have a msg object to work off, anything outside of that throws the whole `message is undefined error`. Mentioning this because I was doing some testing, and if placing this conditional inside the `bot.on(message)` function it doesn't even seem to filter correctly and still shows all events for all servers, rather than the set `GUILD_ID`